# NSOperationQueue blocks UI update of a UITableView when any cell contains a UISwitch

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsoperationqueue, uiswitch

I'm developing an iPhone app which does a lot of mathematical computations, which take about 5-6 seconds, but repeated several times (so, usually, take about 50-60 seconds in total). The full computation set may be repeated several time all together. Each computation is encapsulated in a `NSOperation`.

I am having an issue where during *first* run of computations if an app tries to show a `UITableView` where any of the cells have a `UISwitch`, all app UI would freeze until `NSOperationQueue` with computations becomes empty. (In my app, if user tries to open in-app preferences, which contain such table view, before first run of computations finishes, the UI freezes).

It took me about a week of banging my head at the freezing to pin point conditions when it happens. Below is the code which reproduces the issue in my app. If you run the it and press "Show table" before all 5 operations finish, the UI will freeze until the queue is empty (decrease the added number if operations finish too fast on your machine).

If I replace `NSOperationQueue` with GCD, the issue disappears. If I replace `UISwitch` with a `UIButton`, the issue disappears as well. I'm running Xcode 6.4 (6E35b).

Sometimes the UI does not freeze in this demo code (however, it freezes always in my actual app), but re-running it makes it appear eventually. Also, I have found that setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 2 on my machine (2 core 2009 MBP) makes the issue disappear, but setting it to higher number makes it occur more frequently.

Any, even remote, suggestions on this would be highly appreciated.

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    private let queue = NSOperationQueue()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Show table", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "showTable:")

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

        let screenBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        window = UIWindow(frame: screenBounds)
        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        setUpComputations()

        return true
    }

    func showTable(sender: UIBarButtonItem!) {
        let tableViewController = TableViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableViewController)
        window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        println("showed table")
    }

    private func setUpComputations() {
        // queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 2

        for i in 0...5 {
            // dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {

            queue.addOperationWithBlock {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    println("starting operation \(i)")
                }

                var sum = 0.0
                for _ in 0...5 {
                    while sum < 1000.0 {
                        sum += 1.0e-6
                    }
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    println("finishing operation \(i)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

internal final class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    func dismiss(sender: UIBarButtonItem!) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Done, target: self, action: "dismiss:")
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? UITableViewCell
            ?? UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Some text"

        cell.accessoryView = UISwitch()
        // cell.accessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(.InfoLight) as! UIButton

        return cell
    }
}
```

**Addendum:** Thanks to *Rob*'s input, I've noticed that setting `qualityOfService = .Background` on operation, not the queue, seems to fix the problem. Namely, replace `setUpComputations` above with

```
private func setUpComputations() {
    for i in 0...5 {
        let operation = NSBlockOperation {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                println("starting operation \(i)")
            }

            var sum = 0.0
            for _ in 0...5 {
                while sum < 1000.0 {
                    sum += 1.0e-6
                }
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                println("finishing operation \(i)")
            }
        }

        operation.qualityOfService = .Background
        queue.addOperation(operation)
    }
}
```

Comment: In my tests, the problem doesn't go away if you use GCD. It goes away if you use low priority queue (in your example, the background priority queue). When I created my own GCD concurrent queue with a QoS greater than "utility" or used higher priority global queue, I experienced the same problem you had with operation queue.

Comment: This is fascinating. It's almost as if there's something going on during the instantiation of the UI that is waiting for an idle CPU. I also noticed, though, if you momentarily defer `setUpComputations` (e.g. `dispatch_after`), the problem also disappears, and both the UI and background tasks run smoothly currently. It looks like it's just during that launch phase...

Comment: Rob, thanks very much for you input. I tinkered with quality of service for operations and operation queues. Setting qualityOfService = .Background on _operation_, not the queue fixes the problem in both my app and the code above. But the issue itself still remains. My guess on all of this is that queues are reused internally and, apparently, queue created by my code, gets reused by UISwitch somehow.

Comment: I hesitate to postulate any specific, detailed theories about what's going, as there's no way of really knowing, but it's a bug arising from a confluence of factors and, IMHO, warrants a report: http://bugreport.apple.com